how get -> ( path of the photo file for face-picture-comparator module (pypi.org) in django project root in file utils.py )?
in Windows 10 enterprise , vscode 1.88.0 , Django==5.0.3 , face-picture-comparator==0.0.4 , face-recognition==1.3.0 , face_recognition_models==0.3.0.

How can I give the face-picture-comparator module the path of the photo stored in the sqlite database and in the static folder in my Django project root in file -> utils.py ?

Consider utils.py in django project root folder:
from face_picture_comparator import load_img
from face_picture_comparator import comparation
from face_picture_comparator import plot
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders
from django.templatetags.static import static


def get_face_compare_result(image, image_compare):
    # result = finders.find(image_compare)
    # print(result)
    image_compare = load_img.get_image_file(???)
    image = load_img.get_image_file(???)

    #  message_result = comparation.confront_faces_message(image, image_compare)
    #  message_result = comparation.confront_faces_message(image, image_compare)

    comparison_result = comparation.confront_faces(
        image, image_compare)
    return comparison_result


my error :
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/images/user_profile_image_authenticate/barjawandsaman%2540gmail.com/barjawandsamangmail.com-3140735494931184150742764881890058937-imageProfileAuthenticate.PNG'
[17/Jun/2024 14:14:07] "POST /home/api/v1/authenticating_manager_login_by_face/ HTTP/1.1" 500 132469

spot : i search many questions in this forum and other forums in google but i did not find my answer because in this module (face-picture-comparator - pypi.org) i can not find path for image file that here is my input in utils.py -> image = load_img.get_image_file(???)
and this module in pure python in other python project is working currectly and do not have problems !!! and my problems only is path of input of code (???) -> image = load_img.get_image_file(???) in module face-picture-comparator - pypi.org in django project root folder ... please find this path of image file?


